# How to set value for local group policy(gpedit.msc) using power shell script

Tags: powershell, group-policy

I want to access this path `Computer Configuration\Policies\Windows Settings\Security Settings\Account Policies\Password Policy\Maximum password age` in local group policy editor and modify its value through powershell script. I have tried to import module group (`Get-Command -Module group*`) but no methods/module is found.I have tried the following way in powershell and it didn't work.

```
Set-ItemProperty -Path \Computer Configuration\Windows Settings\Security Settings\Account Policies\Password Policy -Name Maximum password age -Value 20
```

Can someone help me in modifying the value through powershell scripting.

> I am new to powershell scripting,so please ignore if any wrong info is
>   provided.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

For parameters like max password age, I think best way is to use net.exe commant. Try to execute

```
net.exe accounts /?
```

For more complicated group policies in computer without domain, you can prepare policies in one computer, export it to file, and inport in other computers, by using secedit.exe

Try to google secedit /export, secedit /import usage

You can call secedit from powershell without any problems

Comment: Thanks @Micheal , secedit export/import worked in my case.  Got group policy objects from source in csv file 

`Secedit /export /cfg C:\Security.csv`
`Auditpol /backup /file:C:\Audit.ini`

Copied in the target machine

`secedit /configure /cfg C:\Windows\System32\GroupPolicy\Security.csv /db defltbase.sdb /verbose`
`Auditpol /restore /file:C:\Windows\System32\GroupPolicy\audit.ini`

Answer (score 0):

You can find it in windows registry, HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Netlogon\Parameters
MaximumPasswordAge REG_DWORD

Comment: Thank you Micheal for the answer , I want to know in general whether it is possible to set local group policy editor values .I have set rules to change manually , so i thought if it can be set from powershell through a script.

Answer (score 0):

You can get/set Registry values, somewhat counter-intuitively with the [get/set]-itemproperty commands.

Example:

```
Get-ItemProperty HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\WinRM\Service\ -Name AllowCredSSP
```

However, this likely won't reflect in the Local Group Policy Editor interface.

Look up LGPO.exe, documentation is scarce, but it seems to work:
https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/secguide/2016/01/21/lgpo-exe-local-group-policy-object-utility-v1-0/

(Current download is in the "Security Compliance Toolkit")
https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=55319